# How do I perfectly align 1. a. b. 2. a. b. formatting?

Tags: support, bug

So I've posted [this answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/90823/34942) but I cannot seem to be able to perfectly align the formatting no matter what I do if I want to do the following:

2. a. To reduce:

   - don't wrap it
   - leave it in the oven to cool down with the oven slightly open so that most of the moisture can escape

   b. to enhance:

   - Wrap in tin foil before putting it in the oven
   - Wrap it in micro-wave resistant plastic foil the moment it comes out of the oven

(specifically asking about the ugly CRLF between "to reduce"  and "don't")

*Is it me or is it Stack Exchange?*